# Error in starting java application as windows services

Tags: java, windows-services

I have downloaded commom-daemon tool and used with a java application. I have created a bat file as shown below

```
set SERVICE_NAME=sample
set PR_INSTALL=D:\commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows-signed\prunsrv.exe
 
REM Service log configuration
set PR_LOGPREFIX=%SERVICE_NAME%
set PR_LOGPATH=D:\logs
set PR_STDOUTPUT=D:\logs\stdout.txt
set PR_STDERROR=D:\logs\stderr.txt
set PR_LOGLEVEL=Error
 
REM Path to java installation
set PR_JVM=C:\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
set PR_CLASSPATH=D:\commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows-signed\Daemon.jar
 
REM Startup configuration
set PR_STARTUP=auto
set PR_STARTMODE=jvm
set PR_STARTCLASS=com.SomeService
set PR_STARTMETHOD=start
 
REM Shutdown configuration
set PR_STOPMODE=jvm
set PR_STOPCLASS=com.SomeService
set PR_STOPMETHOD=stop
 
REM JVM configuration
set PR_JVMMS=256
set PR_JVMMX=1024
set PR_JVMSS=4000
set PR_JVMOPTIONS=-Duser.language=DE;-Duser.region=de
```

In cmd , I install the service using the command

```
prunsrv.exe //IS//sample
```

After this, a service named sample become available in the list of services and when I tried to start it it shows:

> Windows could not start the sample on Local Computer. For more information review the System event log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor and refer to the server specific
>
> error code 1

**UPDATED**
When I run

```
prunsrv.exe //ES//sample
```

it shows

```
The data area passed to a system call is too small.
Failed to start service
```

Can any one help me in this?

Comment: What does System event log tell?

Comment: where can I find Sysetm event log...

Comment: In Event Viewer. Start > Run > `eventvwr`

Comment: Event log is "The sample service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
Incorrect function"

Comment: And that's it? No more details?

Comment: Try to reduce required memory and see what's happen. I hope your program can start without 256M of heap.

Comment: In details tab, there is some details such as             
- EventData 

  param1 sample 
  param2 %%1 
   730061006D0070006C0065000000

Comment: so I want to comment that line or  do I want to reduce the value

Comment: Even though I removed the JVM configuration...it still says the same error

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. In my case (not yours exactly), the problem was the jvm.dll path, because the variable %JAVA_HOME% has spaces. So to solve this, I modify the assignment

```
set CG_PATH_TO_JVM=%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

to

```
set CG_PATH_TO_JVM="%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
```

and that's all.

Also, you could check the variables assignment with this command:

```
prunmgr//ES//yourservicename_as_in_windows
```

Answer (score 3):

To help others troubleshooting.

If you look at:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html

There is a parameter:

```
--LogPath
```

which defaults to:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\Apache
```

A log file is generated there which contains some additional error messages and possibly useful information.
The original questioner changed the log path to:

```
set PR_LOGPATH=D:\logs
```

So looking there would be the appropriate thing to do in their case.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this cryptic error message 'The data area passed to a system call is too small.' with no further information in either the startup log or the Windows/System32/LogFiles/Apache/ logs on Win 8/Server 2008.

I had renamed my packages and the --StartClass and --StopClass parameters were wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with OscarSan that a space in %JAVA_HOME% could cause the "error code 1" problem. I solve this problem by re-installing JDK 1.8 to change the installation path from **C:\Program Files Java\jdk1.8.0_144** to **C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144**. Problem solved.